# How to invoke java method from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

As described in the title, what I am trying to achieve is the following:

1. Create java object
2. Pass it to JavaScript
3. Invoke a method (a setter for instance) on the passed object
4. Continue work with the object in java

I am using the scripting included in java.
I will be happy if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're working with the ScriptEngine framework, this is really easy. You can "pass" Java objects to JavaScript in two ways:

1. You can "seed" the execution environment for JavaScript code and arrange for Java objects to just be "there" in the global namespace
2. You can pass Java objects in as arguments to JavaScript functions.

You can also access Java constructors from JavaScript and instantiate Java objects if you want.

To do the first thing, you have to set up the "bindings" for the script engine. It's just like a Map:

```
final Bindings globals = engine.createBindings();
globals.put("foo", yourObject);
```

Now, when JavaScript code runs in that engine, the global symbol "foo" will serve as a reference to a Java object.  You can bind in as many references as you like.

If you want to pass a Java object as a parameter to a JavaScript function, the first thing you need is a way to *call* a JavaScript function. To do that, you use the "invokeFunction" or "invokeMethod" method exposed by the "Invocable" interface:

```
final Object result = ((Invocable) engine).invokeMethod(context, methodName, arg, arg, ... );
```

The "context" there is just a reference to something you want `this` to refer to in the function that's called.  The "methodName" is just a string giving the name of your global JavaScript function.

Java classes are available to the JavaScript environment via their fully-qualified pathnames:

```
var javaHashMap = new java.util.HashMap();
```

That would give you a Java HashMap instance as a JavaScript variable.

Comment: Can you please provide a simple code for this? Now I'm using "put" with key and object, but not sure if this is the way you say. And I have another problem - with importPackage. I know that in rhino you just add scope = new ImporterTopLevel(cx), but how can I achieve this in ScriptEngine?

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. What I use now is the first method you explained. But when I try to access foo.getFooName() from js, it tells me that foo is undefined. If I instantiate an object from within the js, the same method works.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you, I just had to set the scope -> engine.setBindings(globals, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE); Now everything works perfect. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Ah yes - sorry, I was looking through the "wrapper" code I wrote last year for my application, so I probably missed that important step :-)  Glad that it is working for you now!